# Por que o uso do parêntesis afeta uma expressão matemática combinada com uma concatenação?

Tags: php

Por que disso:

```
echo "Você nasceu em ". (date('Y') - 20); //Retorna correto, no caso, se a idade for 20, retorna 1997
echo "Você nasceu em ". date('Y') - 20; // Retorna -20
```

Por que que **nesse caso em específico**, com e sem o parenteses, retorna valores diferentes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com os parêntesis é feito primeiro o calculo `date('Y') - 20` que da `1997` e de seguida concatenado com a `string` que dá o texto:

> Você nasceu em 1997

Sem os parêntesis é feito primeiro a concatenação com o ano, dando:

> Você nasceu em 2017

Depois convertido em inteiro para se poder subtrair os `20`. Convertendo `"Você nasceu em 2017"` em inteiro dá `0` pois a primeira letra é um `"V"` e não números:

```
var_dump((int)("Você nasceu em ". date('Y'))); //escreve int(0)
```

Quando subtrai com `20` vai dar `-20`

Logo é importante especificar a ordem das operações.

Comment: Entendi, no caso ele pega a string também. Achei que ele só resolvia a operação que fiz. Mas então entendi, obrigado Isac! E obrigado aos demais também!

Answer (score 3):

Parenteses assim como na matemática dão prioridade para alguma operação, por isso o primeiro `echo` funciona como o esperado ou seja faz a conta e depois escreve o resultado.

P1, P2 = Ordem das prioridades

```
echo "Você nasceu em ". (date('Y') - 20);
                             P1----^
P2-----------^
```

Já o segundo funciona de forma diferente, o interpretador do php tenta resolver tudo de uma vez na ordem que ele acha correto, nesse é pega a string `"Você nasceu em ".` concatena com o resulta de `date()` e tenta substrair com menos -20, como a string gerada não é um número automáticamente é convertida para zero, por isso o resultado é -20 veja que o trecho `Você nasceu em` não é impresso.

```
echo "Você nasceu em ". date('Y') - 20;
        P1---^---------------^
                            p2---^
```

Answer (score 3):

Na expressão `echo "Você nasceu em ". date('Y') - 20`, você está subtraindo a concatenação da string com a data.

Para você entender melhor, seria a mesma coisa de você fazer isso:

```
echo "Você nasceu em 2017" - 20;
```

Por isso é importante usar o parêntesis. Pois em tais casos, é primeiro processado a expressão dentro do parêntesis para depois fazer a concatenação.

*Dica*: Em casos assim, eu costumo usar a função `sprintf` para formatar melhor a string:

```
echo sprintf("Você nasceu em %d", date('Y') - 20);
```

Veja um teste no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/cJ2V96)

*Nota*: Dependendo da versão do PHP que você estiver usando (creio que a partir da versão 7), você poderá receber um erro caso faça uma operação como essa mencionada na pergunta:

> A non-numeric value encountered