# Operação matemática entre string e numero em php

Tags: php

Qual é a explicação para esses resultados adversos se nas duas operações estou subtraindo uma string de um numero?

A operação abaixo

```
echo "Você nasceu em ". date('Y') - 20;
```

Retorna -20

e as operações abaixo

```
echo date('Y') . "Você nasceu em " - 20;

echo "2017 Você nasceu em " - 20;
```

Retorna 2007

Comment: Isso não foi explicado na outra pergunta?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Não, presta atenção nos resultados acima, são diferentes

Comment: Acredito que responda: [Por que no PHP a expressão “2 + '6 maçãs'” é igual a 8?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80767/91)

Comment: @rray, boa, essa eu não tinha visto na pesquisa,  Valeu

Comment: E que também foi explicado na [pergunta que gerou a dúvida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/223634/5878). o Isac comentou sobre este *cast* de *string* para *int* na resposta dele.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Negativo, ninguém falou claramente dessa forma "O mecanismo de interpretação do PHP funciona da seguinte forma, caso a primeira parte da string seja um número válido ele é convertido(int ou float) e o resto é descartado, ......." como rray indicou

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, não estamos respondendo para pessoas com alto grau de conhecimento e principalmente quanto ao linguajar empregado, por exemplo, cast de string, muitos voarão ao ouvir isso.

Comment: E como de praxe, downvoto na minha pergunta. Isso acrescenta muito ao site. Porque não negativaram a outra https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/223634/por-que-o-uso-do-par%C3%AAntesis-afeta-uma-express%C3%A3o-matem%C3%A1tica-combinada-com-uma-con tambem já que existe uma resposta em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80767/por-que-no-php-a-express%C3%A3o-2-6-ma%C3%A7%C3%A3s-%C3%A9-igual-a-8

Comment: A outra pergunta foca no problema de utilizar, ou não, os parêntesis, então a resposta seria focada mais na precedência dos operadores. A sua pergunta já está mais na análise que o PHP faz em *string* numéricas. Não sei explicar o *down-vote*, mas seria duplicata da pergunta que o rray indicou, certo?

Comment: Veja que eu disse que o *foco* da resposta foi a precedência dos operadores, isso não significa que foi exclusivamente isso.

Comment: correto, mas eu não estaria obrigado a ler as respostas já que não se tratava do mesmo foco e minha pesquisa não retornou a indicada pelo rray. Digitem na caixa de pesquisa "Operação matemática entre string e numero em php" e vejam o retorno!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A conversão de string para inteiro depende do formato da string, assim o PHP avalia o formato da string e caso não possua nenhum valor numérico será convertido para 0(zero). Caso possua valor numérico em sua **primeira posição** o valor será considerado e caso o valor não seja na primeira posição será desconsiderado. Veja o exemplo:  [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/9DBXUS)

```
$string = (int) 'Muitas casas';

var_dump( $string ); // int(0)

$string2 = (int) '10 casas aproximadamente';

var_dump( $string2 ); // int(10)

$string3 = (int) 'Exatamente 10 casas';

var_dump( $string3 ); // int(0)
```

Veja mais em [Aprender PHP](http://aprenderphp.com.br/artigo/conversao-de-tipos-de-dados-no-php/)