# A lógica por trás de como o PHP interpreta a concatenação de string e números?

Tags: php

Estava fazendo um quiz de perguntas para a certificação do PHP e apareceu uma pergunta que me deixou inquizilado:

Qual será a saída do seguinte fragmento do código?

```
<?php
    echo 'hello'. 1 + 2 . '34';
?>
```

Resumindo: A saída será 234. Executei via linha de comando com o PHP 7.0 e 5.6 para confirmar e **o resultado continuou o mesmo**.

Ainda não encontrei uma lógica de como o PHP chegou neste resultado e eu gostaria de entender. Quem puder me explicar agradeço.

OBS.: Caso este não seja o local indicado para esta pergunta, favor comentar que irei excluí-la.

Comment: estei em meu terminao com `PHP 7.0` e recebo o erro: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.1' (T_DNUMBER), expecting ',' or ';' in php shell code on line 1`

Comment: Esse código aí da erro devido a falta de espaços.

Comment: Perdão pela falta de espaços.  Esqueci de colocar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pergunta verifica seu conhecimento sobre dois aspectos da linguagem: como o PHP trata *strings* dentro de uma operação matemática - isto é, como ocorre o *cast* de *string* para um número - e a precedência dos operadores.

O primeiro aspecto foi comentado nas outras respostas e é muito bem discutido em:

[Por que no PHP a expressão "2 + '6 maçãs'" é igual a 8?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80767/5878)

Resumindo, ao avaliar uma *string* para convertê-la para um valor numérico, o PHP verificará o conteúdo da esquerda para a direita. Se os primeiros caracteres forem um valor numérico válido, então ele é mantido como resultado. Se não for um valor válido, o retorno será 0.

```
var_dump((float) "1foo");    // float(1)
var_dump((float) "1.9foo");  // float(1.9)
var_dump((float) "foo3.14"); // float(0)
```

O segundo aspecto, não citado nas outras respostas e fundamental para a análise correta é a precedência dos operadores. Os operadores utilizados são o de concatenação, `.`, e a adição, `+`. Ao verificar a tabela de precedência de operadores na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.precedence.php):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que ambos os operadores possuem a mesma precedência, portanto a expressão será analisada da esquerda para a direita, operador a operador.

```
'hello'. 1 + 2 .'34';
```

1. O primeiro operador é de concatenação, então gera-se o valor `'hello1'`;
2. O segundo operador é de adição, então o valor `'hello1'` é primeiro avaliado como numérico, retornando 0, sendo adicionado com 2, resultando em 2;
3. O terceiro operador é de concatenação, então gera-se o valor `'234'`;

Este processo fica evidente ao avaliar os *opcodes* gerados pelo [VLD](https://3v4l.org/HGoZk/vld#output):

```
line     #* E I O op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3     0  E >   ADD                                              ~0      'hello1', 2
         1        CONCAT                                           ~1      ~0, '34'
         2        ECHO                                                     ~1
         3      > RETURN                                                   1
```

Perceba que, para o PHP, a primeira operação ocorrerá mesmo antes da expressão ser avaliada; isso porquê ambos os operadores são constantes.

Conforme o site [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/HGoZk), a mesma saída é gerada em todas as versões testadas, embora apenas em versões superiores à 7.1 que um alerta é emitido sobre a conversão de uma *string* não numérica.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para demonstrar como a precedência de operadores é importante neste caso, basta substituir a adição por divisão. Conforme a tabela de precedência, a divisão possui uma precedência maior que a concatenação, então será avaliada antes. Veja:

```
echo 'hello'. 1 / 2 .'34';  // Resultará: hello0.534
```

Isso porquê ao avaliar a expressão, a divisão será executada antes, retornando o valor `0.5`, e após, as duas concatenações serão executadas, retornando `hello0.534`.

Comment: Toda informação bem aplicada gera conhecimento. Acredito que tratou o problema como um todo de forma didática.

Answer (score 5):

Primeiro o PHP concatena o valor `hello` mais o número `1` isso gera um número inválido logo é convertido zero então efetua a conta 0 + 2 e contatena o resultado da  soma com `34` que termina como a string `234`.

```
echo 'hello'. 1 + 2 .'34';
  ------------^   ^--------
    1 parte         2 parte 
    valor: 0    +   valor: 2
```

Esse código é equivalmente a esse:

```
echo ('hello'. 1) + 2 .'34';
```

**Relaciondas:**

[Por que no PHP a expressão "2 + '6 maçãs'" é igual a 8?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80767/91)

[Operação matemática entre string e numero em php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/223671/91)

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que quando o PHP converte strings para numero ele dá 0 se a string não tiver digitos no inicio. Ou seja:

```
echo intval('4string'); // 4
echo intval('string4'); // 0
echo intval('string'); // 0
```

Então o que acontece é:

- concatena a primeira string com numero dá 'hello1',
- depois vê o operador `+`, converte `hello1` para numero (que dá 0),
- depois soma esse 0 com 2 (que dá 2),
- e por fim concatena 2 com a string `34`.