# Por quê no PHP e no MySQL ! é convertido em 0 em alguns casos?

Tags: php, mysql

A pergunta é o titulo por sí só, no PHP podemos fazer:

```
var_dump((int) "!");
```

E receber `int(0)`.

E no MySQL podemos fazer:

```
SELECT campo_int FROM tabela WHERE campo_int = "!"
```

E se esse `'campo_int'` for `'0'` ele retorna o registro.

- Por quê isso acontece?
- Isso tem alguma utilidade planejada pelos desenvolvedores da linguagem?

Comment: Me parece que são dois comportamentos distintos e até opostos. Jura que o MySQL faz isso?

Comment: `!` não é um int válido logo retorna `false` com o cast aplicado vira zero. Talvez seja o mesmo caso [dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227679/91). Já no MySQL desconfio que não está configurando como `strict mode`.

Comment: @Maniero sim!! errei agora pouco em uma query, e reparei nisso, só retorna em campos int outros tipos não

Comment: A pergunta está mal formulada, o MySQL retorna qualquer coisa que não `!`. E de fato são duas coisas distintas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você executa este comando:

```
var_dump((int) "!");
```

Na verdade ele retorna falso já que não conseguiu fazer o cast para int, se você fazer desta forma por exemplo:

```
var_dump((int) "qualquerCoisaString");
```

Vai retorna 0 da mesma forma, já que ele não consegue converter para int, e no mysql é a mesma coisa, se você fazer assim:

```
SELECT campo_int FROM tabela WHERE campo_int = "qualquerCoisaString"
```

Ele vai retornar os valores do campo_int que tenha o valor 0, já que sua expressão retornou 0(falso).

Comment: Realmente é isso mesmo, parece que em int se não for int ele assume o comportamento booleano, achei confuso, parece até uma falha